# Modify value of wxTextCtrl from wxDialog in Python

Tags: python, class, wxpython

I have the following code:

```
import wx

class CotizadorWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CotizadorWindow,self).__init__(None)
        self.CreateInteriorWindowComponents()

        self.SetTitle(u"Cotizador")

   def CreateInteriorWindowComponents(self):
       self.hbox=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
       self.panel1=wx.Panel(self,-1,style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
       self.SetSizer(self.hbox)
       self.Centre()
       self.hbox.Add(self.panel1,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,3)


       wx.StaticText(self.panel1,label=u"Cotización", pos=(10,10))
       self.bxCotizacion=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel1,size=(80,-1),pos=(80,8))


       self.btnAltaCliente=wx.Button(self.panel1,label='Alta cliente', pos=(100,37))
       self.btnAltaCliente.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.Alta)


    def Alta(self,event):
        altacliente=DlgAltaCliente(None, title='Nuevo Cliente')
        altacliente.ShowModal()
        altacliente.Destroy()

    def ClearCliente2(self):
        self.bxCotizacion.Value='1'


class DlgAltaCliente (wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kw):
        super(DlgAltaCliente,self).__init__(*args,**kw)

        self.InitUI()
        self.SetSize((200,200))
        self.SetTitle("Alta de Cliente")

    def InitUI(self):
        pnl=wx.Panel(self)
        vbox=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        hbox=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        okButton=wx.Button(self,label='OK')
        closeButton=wx.Button(self,label='Cancelar')
        hbox.Add(okButton)
        hbox.Add(closeButton, flag=wx.LEFT,border=5)

        vbox.Add(pnl,proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND,border=5)
        vbox.Add(hbox,flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)

        self.SetSizer(vbox)
        okButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.EvtGuardarCliente)
        closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.EvtOnClose)

    def EvtGuardarCliente(self,event):

        self.Destroy()
        cotizador=CotizadorWindow()
        cotizador.ClearCliente2()

   def EvtOnClose(self,event):
       self.Destroy()


app=wx.App()
frame=CotizadorWindow()
frame.Show()
frame.Maximize()
app.MainLoop()
```

In the 2nd Class I create a dialog, after is closed the information of the dialog should be transfered to the component in the 1st Class component. It doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in the event handler for the ok case, you are creating a new instance of CortizadorWindow instead of accessing a reference to the already instantiated one.

Comment: Thank you, I'm very new at Python. Could you please explain me how to access to the reference already initiated?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use event handlers for a dialog's Ok and Cancel buttons.  Just use the stock IDs wx.ID_OK and wx.ID_CANCEL for those buttons and the default handlers will do the right thing for you, including validating the dialogs controls if they have validators and then calling EndModal.

Then in the code that creates and shows the dialog the typical usage pattern is something like this:

```
def Alta(self,event):
    altacliente=DlgAltaCliente(None, title='Nuevo Cliente')
    if altacliente.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        # fetch values from the dialog
        self.someValue = altacliente.getSomeValue()
    altacliente.Destroy()
```

And using the dialog as a context manager is also possible, and it will automatically call Destroy for you when it is done:

```
def Alta(self, event):
    with DlgAltaCliente(None, title='Nuevo Cliente') as dlg:
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            # do something with dlg values...
```

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't properly made. I want to update the field (any field of the CotizadorWindow) after the dialog box is closed. If I put a button inside CotizadorWindow class the field is updated correclty, but when I try to call the function from the DlgAltaCliente class it doesn't work.